# How to speed up sql query execution?

Tags: sql, subquery, query-optimization, where-clause

The task is to execute the sql query:

```
select * from x where user in (select user from x where id = '1')
```

The subquery contains about 1000 id so it takes a long time.
Maybe this question was already there, but how can I speed it up? (if it is possible to speed up please write for PL SQL and T-SQL or at least one of them).

Comment: What do you mean "the subquery contains about 1000 id"?

Comment: `tsql` <> `plsql`. I removed these conflicting tags, please tag only one database: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by rewriting the `in` condition to `exists`:

```
select * 
from x 
where exists (select 1 from x x1 where x.user = x.user and x1.id = 1)
```

Then, consider an index on `x(user, id)` - or `x(id, user)` (you can try both and see if one offers better improvement that the other).

Another possibility is to use window functions:

```
select * 
from (
    select x.*, max(case when id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by user) flag
    from x
) x
where flag = 1
```

This might, or might not, perform better than the `not exists` solution, depending on various factors.

Answer (score 1):

`id`s are usually unique.  Is it sufficient to do this?

```
select x.*
from x
where id in ( . . . );
```

You would want an index on `id`, if it is not already the primary key of the table.